# Printing a linked list in the right order

Tags: c, printing, linked-list

I am trying to print a linked list that I create in C, but it is printed in the wrong order and I can't understand why. I am assigning the pointers correctly. Can someone help me pls ? Here is my code:

```
struct list_el {
    int val;
    struct list_el * next;
};

typedef struct list_el item;

void main() {
    item *curr, *head;
    int value;
    head = NULL;

    scanf("%d", &value);

    while (value != 0){
        scanf("%d", &value);
        curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
        curr->val = value;
        curr->next = head;
        head = curr;
}
    curr = head;

    while (curr) {
        printf("%d\n", curr->val);
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &value);` at while-loop move to loop-end. also change to `int main()`

Comment: its printing nothing now ;/

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d", &value);

while (value != 0){
    curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
    curr->val = value;
    curr->next = head;
    head = curr;
    scanf("%d", &value);
}
```

Comment: the values are still printed in the reverse order. I am entering the values for example 16 14 12 and 0 and prints 12 14 16...

Comment: @TomisAristidou It is because you are connecting the link in reverse order. The entered value you are connected to the front of the `head`.

Comment: What I should change ? I am noob at link lists ..;/

Comment: Cheeky answer - create a temporary list from the first, which will reverse it again.

Comment: @TomisAristidou see rpattiso's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the list to be in the same order as the input, you need to append onto the end (tail) of the list.

```
int main() {
    item *curr, *head, *tail;
    int value;
    head = NULL;

    scanf("%d", &value);

    while (value != 0) {
        curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
        curr->val = value;
        curr->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) {
           head = tail = curr;
        } else {
           tail->next = curr;
           tail = curr; 
        }
        scanf("%d", &value);
     }

     ...
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, that's what i get for cutting & pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. A dummy node is created in the list to avoid dealing explicitly with corner cases (empty list, etc).

```
int main() {
    item *curr, *head;
    int value=-1;
    head = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
    curr = head;

    while (value != 0){
        scanf("%d", &value);
        curr->val = value;
        curr->next = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr = head;

    while (curr->next) {
        printf("%d\n", curr->val);
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Gives

```
$ ./a.out 
1
2
3
4
5
0
1
2
3
4
5
0
```

Comment: `curr->next` should be set to `NULL` immediately after the first while loop.